# How do neutrino masses change the shape of the $\beta$ decay spectrum?

Tags: radiation, neutrinos, radioactivity, beyond-the-standard-model, weak-interaction

It is more-or-less established that neutrinos have masses. But as of now, $\nu$-masses have not been directly measured in the laboratory. But I heard a talk where the speaker said that efforts are going on in that direction. In that respect, he pointed out that nonzero $\nu$-masses would change the shape of the $\beta$ decay spectrum with zero $\nu$-masses and in particular, at the endpoint of the spectrum. I could not completely follow. I couldn't catch him after the talk to interact. I request someone to explain why a nonzero $\nu$-mass expected to the shape of the $\beta$ decay spectrum. Some mathematical expression is extremely welcome. Thanks!

Comment: look at this https://www.radioprotection.org/articles/radiopro/pdf/2014/04/radiopro140017.pdf to understand the complexity of what you are asking  also this https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0909/0909.2104.pdf

Comment: Are you familiar with what the beta decay spectrum represents and how it is derived via kinematics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: beta decay spectrum with nonzero electron neutrino mass]
In a certain radioactive decay (such as tritium decay) a fixed amount of energy is released (the Q-value, $Q$). Because $\beta$ decay is a three-body decay,
$$
X\to Y+ e^- + \overline{\nu}_e
$$
the energy electron $e^-$  receives can be anything from zero to maximum amount. In the case of maximal energy, the neutrino $\overline{\nu}_e$ has zero kinetic energy. If neutrinos are massless, there is no lower bound on the total energy the neutrino receives. However if neutrinos have mass, say $m(\nu_e) = 1$ eV, then the smallest possible energy it possesses is simply its mass-energy, $mc^2$. Therefore the largest possible energy the electron can receive is lower in the massive-neutrino case, and the endpoint of the electron energy spectrum is reached at lower energy. This is a very small effect, which is why it is yet unseen. See the above pic for enlightenment.